Add Custom Text to Category Thumbnail Image in WooCommerce Category Archive Page
I've been trying to add custom text on particular category thumbnail image to display in category archive pages. I created a custom menu including a table containing two columns. The category (the restaurant in my case) and the two radio buttons ("on" or "off") like:

I want to display "Closed" custom text on the particular categories' thumbnail in category archive pages with overlay background, when the user select "on" in particular categories. Could you please help?
I have tried the following code and I managed to get the categories to the table:
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Menu Plugin
Description: Adds a custom admin menu with a table containing text and radio buttons.
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Name
*/
    
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_menu_plugin_add_menu');

function custom_menu_plugin_add_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Close Shop', // Page title
        'Close Shop', // Menu title
        'manage_options', // Capability required to access
        'custom-menu-plugin', // Menu slug (unique identifier)
        'custom_menu_plugin_page', // Callback function to display page content
        'dashicons-admin-generic' // Icon URL or Dashicons class
    );
}

// Display custom menu page
function custom_menu_plugin_page() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h1>Custom Menu Page</h1>';

    echo '<table class="widefat">';
    echo '<thead><tr><th>Shop Name</th><th>Closed</th></tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    $categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );

    // Check if categories exist
    if ($categories) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<tr><td>' . esc_html($category->name) . '</td><td><input type="radio" name="' . esc_attr($category->slug) . '" value="on"> On <input type="radio" name="' . esc_attr($category->slug) . '" value="off" checked> Off</td></tr>';
        }
    }

    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';

    echo '<form method="post" action="' . esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')) . '">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_menu_plugin_form">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Save Changes">';
    echo '</form>';

    echo '</div>';
}


// Handle form submissions
add_action('admin_post_custom_menu_plugin_form', 'custom_menu_plugin_process_form');

function custom_menu_plugin_process_form() {
    $categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat'] );

    // Redirect back to the menu page after processing
    wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=custom-menu-plugin'));
    exit;
}

